# Are game specific communication questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

I have questions that revolve around communication in Magic. It's not a rulings question. For example:

> When I ask "Declare blockers?", often my opponents do not understand. What can I say in order to clearly communicate to my opponent that I would like to move the the Declare Blockers step?

Obviously the question would be a little more detailed if I actually posted it (I might describe my opponent's reactions and the problems it leads to). If it is purely a communication question, is it on topic here?

There is a real need to avoid ambiguous conversation in Magic, but it could be a topic for another site.

Comment: I'm curious: why would you have thought this might _not_ be on topic here?

Comment: @DavidZ For two reasons. First, the *best* way to communicate might be considered subjective. Just looking at the question I posed as an example, can you see how there might be a few "good" answers, but no "correct" ones? Second, the topic is communication. One could argue that communicating clearly isn't really about Magic at all.

Comment: @Rainbolt This kind of thing -- especially in a tournament setting -- is definitely in the scope of Good Subjective though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can ask it here

This is a question about playing Magic the Gathering, intended for Magic the Gathering players and experts, and thus on topic. It's not a topic about its exact mechanics, but we *do* accept questions about games that are outside of play, and this is halfway between both.

This is not e.g. a good question for English.SE, because whoever answers it on English.SE would have to also be a Magic the Gathering player who thoroughly understands the context you're asking about.

Comment: Having spent a small amount of time on English.SE they would have enough experience in MTG be able to answer it, but they wouldn't; they would send it here instead.